# Primefaces droppable from dynamically generated datatable to datatable in different panel

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, droppable

I am trying to get drag and drop on some tables. The source table is dynamically generated from a selectOneMenu->AccordianPanel->datatable. I can point to it from the droppable with a direct path listed below in the datasource but I get a noRowAvailableException upon dropping the attribValue text. Is there any ideas on a path to a solution? If I left something out that needs to be known I apologize and I will update as needed. Thank you.

```
<p:accordionPanel value="#{testBean.attributeList}" var="attribute" id="attribute" >
                                    <p:tab title="#{attribute.displayName}">
                                        <p:dataTable value="#{attribute.valuesList}" var="attribValue" id="attribValue" selectionMode="single" rowKey="#{attribValue}" selection="#{testBean.attribValue}">
                                            <p:column>
                                                <script type='text/javascript'>
                                                    $(".myDraggables").draggable({
                                                        helper: function() {
                                                            return $(this).clone().appendTo('body').css('zIndex', 5).show();
                                                        }
                                                    });
                                                </script>
                                                <h:outputText value="#{attribValue.name}" class="myDraggables" id="actualValue"/>
                                                <p:draggable for="actualValue" revert="true"  />
                                            </p:column>
                                        </p:dataTable>
                                    </p:tab>`
                                </p:accordionPanel>
```

and this is the drop location:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{testBean.subscriptions}" var="subscripList" id="subscriptions">
                                <p:column style="width:648px">
                                    <script type='text/javascript'>
                                        $(".myDroppables").droppable({
                                            accept: '.myDraggables'
                                        });
                                    </script>
                                    <f:facet name="header">
                                        Product Subscriptions
                                    </f:facet>
                                    <h:outputText id="destination" value="#{subscripList.name}" class="myDroppables" />
                                    <p:droppable for="subscriptions" datasource=":mainForm:form:attribute:attribValue">
                                        <p:ajax process="subscriptions" listener="#{testBean.onDrop}" update="subscriptions" />
                                    </p:droppable>
                                </p:column>
                            </p:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually initialize the destination list variable in your bean.

In testBean just replace

```
List subscriptions;
```

with

```
List subscriptions = new ArrayList<>();
```